# Add attachment to Outlook from SharePoint Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, object-model, sharepoint-server

We have a requirement to send Emails from SharePoint with attachments from Document Library.
We have been able to achieve this.

But now the requirement is client want to open outlook and add attachment to it, then send email.

Do anyone have any idea how to open outlook and add the selected attachment to it.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your document library to Outlook, then it is just a matter of drag-and-drop the document to be attached to a new email message.

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/synchronize-sharepoint-2010-content-with-outlook-2010-HA101881295.aspx#_Toc262734694)'s a reference on how to synchronize SharePoint 2010 with Outlook 2010

Comment: Actually the issue is that i have to edit properties of the document so i cannot go with this method..

Comment: So your question is incomplete. You only stated that you need to open outlook and attach a document. Anyhow, if these documents are Word docs, you can edit their properties by opening them right from Outlook, save and attach to a new message.

Comment: we don't want to do it manually, want to automate this.

Comment: what is that *exactly* you want to do automatically? It is totally unclear to me. Try to describe the process you envision a bit clearerly

Comment: we have ceratin documents in document library and we want to mail those documents using outlook to external users, so before mailing those documents we want to edit the properties of documents and we want this to happen on a button click on ribbon. So on click of button it should open outlook and attach the selected documents with properties of the document removed, to outlook. Hope it is clear now.